# Js - prototypal inheritance with object create function

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I am wondering why in this piece of code, when I am trying to access the properties of the object that the `garfield` is made of, in this case `Cat`, I am getting `undefined`:

```
function Cat(){
    this.legs = 2;
    this.species = 'cat';
};

Cat.prototype.makeSound = function() {
    console.log(this.sound); // logs undefined 
};

const garfield = Object.create(Cat);
garfield.sound = 'feed me';
garfield.makeSound();
console.log(garfield.legs) // logs undefined
```

Shouldn't I be able to get down the prototype inheritance chain the access to those properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `OOP` contains "object" in its definition; meaning that you are dealing with objects.

Javascript does something special that it exposes the objects directly, in which you can use them without abstractions (without classes).

To create an object, you can just declare it with `{}`. no need to create a class to get one like in `java` for example.

To use Inheritance directly, you need to have an object, and append things to its prototype.

Here is an example:

```js
const Cat = {
  legs: 2,
  species: 'cat',
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(Cat, {
  makeSound() {
    console.log(this.sound); // logs undefined 
  }
})


const garfield = Object.create(Cat);
garfield.sound = 'feed me';
garfield.makeSound();
console.log(garfield.legs) //2
```

To use Inheritance using functions, you'd have to construct the function first to get the object out of the function (the `this`) and the prototype will automatically be appended to the `this` object.

```js
function Cat(){
    this.legs = 2;
    this.species = 'cat';
};

Cat.prototype.makeSound = function() {
    console.log(this.sound); // logs undefined 
};

const garfield = new Cat();
garfield.sound = 'feed me';
garfield.makeSound();
console.log(garfield.legs) // 2
```

Comment: I don't see a reason to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` here, just put `makeSound` on the `Cat` object.

Answer (score 2):

In your example [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) does **not** create a new instance of the class! It creates a function (because `Cat` is a function and you pass function's prototype)!

Use `new` to create a new instance

```
const garfield = new Cat();
console.log(garfield.legs);
```

or

```
function GarfieldLikeCat() {}
GarfieldLikeCat.prototype = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
GarfieldLikeCat.prototype.constructor = GarfieldLikeCat;
```

to get the classical **inheritance** (not a new instance!).

If you didn't use `this.legs = 2;`, but instead `Cat.prototype.legs = 2;`, you could use `Object.create` to create a new instance

```
function Cat() {}
Cat.prototype.legs = 2;
const garfield = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
console.log(garfield.legs);
```

Comment: +1. but notice that without calling the constructor function, you would not construct the object (ie `legs` and `species` will not get appended to garfield in this example) so its a better approach to either use `new`, use objects directly, or create factory functions.